# How do I prove this derivative?

Tags: calculus

Prove through induction, that the derivative of $f(x)=\frac{4}{4-x^{2}}$ for every natural number is equal to  $$f^{(n)}(x) = n! \left( \frac{1}{(2-x)^{^{n+1}}}+(-1)^{n}\cdot\frac{1}{(2+x)^{^{n+1}}} \right).$$

I have been trying for hours, but neither using the chain rule or quotient rule got me anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Dang ,Welcome to MSE.
As a hint try first to $$\frac{4}{4-x^2}=\frac{a}{2-x}+\frac{b}{2+x}$$ find $a,b$so next rewrite as $$f(x)=a(2-x)^{-1}+b(2+x)^{-1}$$ then after two or three time derivation , you will find the formula which you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Base case:** We simply need to show that the derivative $$f'(x)=4(-2x)(4-x)^{(-2)}$$ is equivalent to the given function $f^{(n)}$ where $n=1$. We can use algebra (hint: use difference of squares!) to show these two are equal.

**Inductive Case:** Suppose it's true that  $f^{(n)}$ as stated is the derivative of  $f^{(n-1)}$ for every number up to $k$. Then write $$ f^{(k+1)}= (f^{(k)})'$$ $$=k!*(\frac{(n+1)(-1)}{(2-x)^{k+2}}+(-1)^k*\frac{n+1}{2+x}^{n+2})$$

All that's left is to show that this expression is equivalent to the given formula $f^{(n)}$ with $n=k+1$, ie: $$ f^{(k+1)} = (k+1)!* (\frac{1}{(2-x)^{k+2}} + (-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{(2+x)^{k+2}}$$

Hope this helps!